# "npm init" does not create node_module folder and other files

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

sorry for novice question.
I have already node in my system. 
`node -v 
 v4.4.0`

```
npm -v
2.14.20
```

To make a new node project i have run the command `npm init`, but it only creates a `pacakage.json` file which contains general information.

Meanwhile I expect it to create basic essential files (a set of files and folder including `node_module` and `index.js`)

What should i do?

Comment: *"What should i do?"* Open your editor and start writing a `index.js` file? `index.js` and `node_modules` are *not* essential for a Node package.

Comment: `npm init` only creates package.json file. to install node packages you need to add package in package.json and run `npm install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After "npm init" you want to install the modules you need by running "npm install  --save<-dev>". This will create a node_modules directory with the relevant modules and will add them to the package.json file so that executing "npm install" will auto' download and install them. 
Regarding auto generating files, some IDEs will do that for you.